# jQuery-UI: Display X and Y of draggable widget

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I'm currently with a jQuery UI that I'm using in a form where I need to send the x and y coordinates to a different page.

I'm currently using [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) where the 'draggable ui' is contained inside a 510x100 px box.

What I need is to get the X coordinates and Y coordinates of the final location of the draggable, and print the coordinates of X in one text input (form) and Y in another.

Any ideas on how to do so?

```
<style>
.draggable { width: 1px; height: 1px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 1px 1px 0; }
#containment-wrapper { width: 510px; height:110px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; }
h3 { clear: left; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
});
</script> <div id="containment-wrapper">


 <div id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
        <p>Motto</p>
 <div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
        <p>Motto</p>

---
Would like to display in a box like this
 <input size="10" type="text" id="mottox" name="mottox" readonly/>
 <input size="10" type="text" id="mottoy" name="mottoy" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the [stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) event of jQueryUI Draggable.

Add:

```
        stop: function(e , ui) {
            $("#mottox").val($(this).position().left);
            $("#mottoy").val($(this).position().top);
        }
```

as a flag to draggable()  (As you have done with containment and scroll). This will fill the values of the inputs with the 'left' and 'top' values of the draggable item as soon as dragging stops.

See a working example of this on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9mjJG/1/

Instead of the stop event, you could also use [drag](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag) which would give more real time updates.